# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'zipped' referenced before assignment: Generator Error

Tags: python, multithreading, keras, multiprocessing, generator

I'm trying to build semantic segmentation model in keras. Since I use a custom data, I decided to write a custom generator to feed it to the keras function `_.fit_generator` and I have reached a dead-end in solving this generator error which says

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'zipped' referenced before assignment
```

After some github and stackover research, I found that "https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1638#issuecomment-182139908" ans is similar to my issue and even this solution doesn't seem to work throwing the same error again

```
def image_segmentation_generator( PROC_DATA, target_size, 
batch_size , gen, do_augment=False):
    if gen=='train':
        images_path = PROC_DATA+'/train_images/images'
        segs_path = PROC_DATA+'/train_labels/labels'
    elif 'val':
        images_path = PROC_DATA+'/val_images/images'
        segs_path = PROC_DATA+'/val_labels/labels'

    img_seg_pairs = get_pairs_from_paths( images_path , segs_path)
    random.shuffle( img_seg_pairs )
    zipped = itertools.cycle( img_seg_pairs  )
    while True:

        X = []
        Y = []
        for _ in range( batch_size) :
            im , seg = next(zipped)
            im = cv2.imread(im , 1 )
            im = cv2.resize(im,(target_size[0],target_size[1]))
            seg = cv2.imread(seg , 0 )
            seg = ia.imresize_single_image(seg, (target_size), 
interpolation='nearest')
            if do_augment:
                img , seg[:,:,0] = augment_seg( img , seg[:,:,0] )
            X.append( get_image_arr(im )  )
            Y.append( get_segmentation_arr( seg )  )

        yield np.array(X) , np.array(Y) 

my_gen = image_segmentation_generator(...)
```

`my_gen.next()` should give me the image and label frames with given batch size.

stack trace:
im , seg = next(zipped)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'zipped' referenced before assignment

How can I fix this?

Comment: check indentation of `zipped = itertools.cycle( img_seg_pairs  )` line, It could be inside `elif` block.

Comment: Source view says you've got mixed tabs and spaces. Find your editor's "convert tabs to spaces" button and hit it, then make sure to not let tabs sneak in again. Also, next time, post the full stack trace.

Comment: The mixed tabs and spaces matter because indentation matters in Python, and Python doesn't treat tabs as 4 spaces. Python 2 uses 8-space tab stops, and Python 3 (which you should really migrate to as soon as possible) treats tabs as inequivalent to any number of spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. There are no issues related to white spaces and tabs. I might have edited the code while posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference.
I have found the workaround for this. It looks like the function object when created as a generator should be self-sustainable with no dependency on extra arguments. Hence the iterator's object with address should be passed along the function.

Zipped = object created before calling image_segmentation_generator_1

def image_segmentation_generator_1(zipped = Zipped, target_size=(1242, 378), batch_size=4, do_augment=False):
    while True:

```
    image_list = []
    label_list = []
    _image_list = []
    _label_list = []
    for _ in range((batch_size/2)) :
        im , seg = next(zipped)
        im = cv2.imread(im , 1 )
        im = cv2.resize(im,(target_size[0],target_size[1]))
        seg = cv2.imread(seg , 0 )
        seg = ia.imresize_single_image(seg, (target_size[0],target_size[1]), interpolation='nearest')
        if do_augment:
            _image_list , _label_list = augment_seg( im , seg)
        else :
            _image_list = im
            _label_list = seg
        _image_list = get_image_arr(_image_list)
        image_list = image_list + _image_list
        label_list = label_list + _label_list

    yield np.array(image_list) , np.array(label_list)
```